# Append an inline image to H1

Tags: jquery, arrays, match

I have a section with the id of 'home'. I have a bit of JS that changes the background image of the 'home' section on page load.

I have 5 background images in total and I have 5 logo images as well. Each logo pairs with a specific background image. How do I alter my code to ensure the correct logo loads with the correct background image? The logo must appear inline, so actually in the HTML document. I've tried appending the logo to a container called 'red-cherry' but all of my code breaks.

My attempt to do this but I understand I haven't tried to check against what background image has been loaded.

**JS**

```
// Create an array of images
var images = ['a-pat.jpg', 'b.jpg', 'c-pat.jpg', 'd-pat.jpg', 'f-pat.jpg'];
var logos = ['cr-pink.png', 'cr-cherry.png', 'cr-green.png', 'cr-blue.png', 'cr-red.png'];

// Display one random one each time the page loads
$('#home').css({'background-image': 'url(../img/wallpaper/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});

$("h1.cherry-red").append({'<img src="../img/logos/' + logos[Math.floor(Math.random() * logos.length)] + '"/>')});
```

**HTML**

```
<section id="home">
    <h1 class="cherry-red"><span>Cherry Red</span></h1>
</section>
```

**For clarity**

*I need to check what background image is being loaded in to #home and then load the correct logo to H1. I need to somehow say if a-pat.png is loaded as a background image ONLY load the logo cr-pink.png*

**Further explanation**

Could I add a bunch of if statements after the bit of code I already have? For example: If images = 'a-pat.png' then append cr-pink.png to H1 else if images = b.jpg then append cr-cherry.png to H1 and so on... Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same random index for both.

```
var images = ['a-pat.jpg', 'b.jpg', 'c-pat.jpg', 'd-pat.jpg', 'f-pat.jpg'];
var logos = ['cr-pink.png', 'cr-cherry.png', 'cr-green.png', 'cr-blue.png', 'cr-red.png'];

var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);

$('#home').css({'background-image': 'url(../img/wallpaper/' + images[rnd] + ')'});
$("h1.cherry-red").append('<img src="../img/logos/' + logos[rnd] + '"/>');
```

Comment: I copied your code but it doesn't work unfortunately. I get a blank page. When I check dev tools no background images are loaded nor does any inline img

Comment: Thats not the case because before my random background images were working and now nothing displays :)

Comment: Oops, didn't see the syntax error in `.append()`. (Keep the JavaScript error console open to see error messages.)

Comment: Ah great now I get random logos as well as random bg images. Progress. Thanks! As per my question though, how do I ensure only the cr-pink.png logo is displayed when the cr-green.jpg background image is displayed? I need to create 5 combinations.

Comment: That's what the `rnd` variable is for. Just make sure `images` and `logos` are in the correct order.

Comment: Ahhhh I see now, thats great! Thanks for your help and answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to generate the random number once:

```
// Display one random one each time the page loads
var imageNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
$('#home').css({'background-image': 'url(../img/wallpaper/' + images[imageNumber] + ')'});
$("h1.cherry-red").append({'<img src="../img/logos/' + logos[imageNumber] + '"/>')});
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't seem to get this to work, when I copy/paste your code nothing happens...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue once and I handled it differently.

I made a page with divs and images

pageimages.html

```
<div id="image1"><image src="myimage1.gif"></div>
<div id="image2"><image src="myimage2.gif"></div>
<div id="image3"><image src="myimage3.gif"></div>
```

I then used jquery load for the images so that the source page was cached on the server.  This was much faster than waiting for each image to load, or worrying about a preload or anything.

```
$('#home').load('pageimages.html #image1');
```

or

```
$('#home').load('pageimages.html #image2');
```

Comment: How did you randomise what images appeared?

Comment: you can do that the same as the answer above and create the string vs hard coding it the way I did.  The important part is the use of jquery load.  I have more complex code and can't really pull it apart.